# How can I transfer the value in one function to another function?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I need to transfer the width value in calcRectArea to calcTriArea so I can calculate the gable area without asking for the width a second time. I'm very new to Python and programming in general, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

```
def main():   

    '''
main adds rectangular area and triangular area to compute the total area
    '''

    rectarea=0
    rectarea=calcRectArea(rectarea)
    print("Rectangular area is now",rectarea)

    triarea=0
    triarea=calcTriArea(triarea)
    print("Triangular area is now",triarea)

    totalarea=triarea+rectarea
    print("The total area of the first house is",totalarea)

    print("For the second house: ")

    rectarea2=0
    rectarea2=calcRectArea(rectarea2)
    print("Rectangular area of second house is now",rectarea2)

    triarea2=0
    triarea2=calcTriArea(triarea2)
    print("Triangular area of the second house is now",triarea2)

    totalarea2=triarea2+rectarea2
    print("The total area of the second house is",totalarea2) 

    totalbothhouses=totalarea+totalarea2
    print("The combined area of both houses is",totalbothhouses)


def calcRectArea(RectAreaTotal):

    '''
calcRectArea prompts the user to enter width, height, and length, computes the
front and side areas, and adds them to compute rectangular area
'''

    width=input("Enter the width: ")
    width=int(width)

    height=input("Enter the height: ")
    height=int(height)

    length=input("Enter the length: ")
    length=int(length)

    front=(width*height)
    side=(length*height)

    RectAreaTotal=(front*2)+(side*2)
    return RectAreaTotal

def calcTriArea(totalgablearea):

    '''
    calcTriArea has the user enter the gable height and computes triangular area
    '''

    gableheight=input("Enter the gable height: ")
    gableheight=int(gableheight)

    totalgablearea=(gableheight)         
    return totalgablearea                       

main()
```

Comment: y dont you trake inputs in your main function ...in this way you willl be able to those inputs in any function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I ended up just globalizing the variables.

Comment: @JoeyCartella NO NO NO! Dont do that. **ALWAYS** avoid globals when you can.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider asking for the values outside your calculation functions:

```
def get_dimensions():
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    width = int(input("Enter the width: "))
    length = int(input("Enter the length: "))

height, width, length = get_dimensions()

# go on to pass the values to your functions
```

There are other much more advanced options, but that should get you started. If you're interested, I can add some other options to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at what a function looks like.

I can write some arbitrary function called foo such that it has a single input and output:

```
def foo(a):
    return a

f = foo(1)  # f == 1
```

I can also write it with 4 inputs and 4 outputs:

```
def foo(a, b, c, d):
    return a, b, c, d

f, g, h, i = foo(1, 2, 3, 4) # f = 1, g = 2, h = 3, i = 4
```

A function definition allows you to specify any number of inputs you desire. You will also notice that in python, you can return multiple values! In your example, you could simply change your current function to accept an extra value.

```
def calcTriArea(totalgablearea):
```

becomes

```
def calcTriArea(totalgablearea, calcRectArea):
```

Now you need to change your return statment in rectArea to return an extra value.

```
return RectAreaTotal, width
```

and now your can access `calcRectArea`'s width in your in your triArea function! You now just need to pass it to the function like so:

```
rectarea, width=calcRectArea(rectarea)
print("Rectangular area is now",rectarea)

triarea=0
triarea=calcTriArea(triarea, width)
print("Triangular area is now",triarea)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values from main and pass it onto the two functions, `calcRectArea` and `calcTriArea`

Check the definitions of the functions including `main` to implement the change:

```
def main():   

    '''
main adds rectangular area and triangular area to compute the total area
    '''

    rectarea=0
    width=input("Enter the width: ")
    width=int(width)
    rectarea=calcRectArea(rectarea,width)
    print("Rectangular area is now",rectarea)

    triarea=0
    triarea=calcTriArea(triarea,width)
    print("Triangular area is now",triarea)

    totalarea=triarea+rectarea
    print("The total area of the first house is",totalarea)

    print("For the second house: ")

    rectarea2=0
    width=input("Enter the width: ")
    width=int(width)
    rectarea2=calcRectArea(rectarea2, width)
    print("Rectangular area of second house is now",rectarea2)

    triarea2=0
    triarea2=calcTriArea(triarea2, width)
    print("Triangular area of the second house is now",triarea2)

    totalarea2=triarea2+rectarea2
    print("The total area of the second house is",totalarea2) 

    totalbothhouses=totalarea+totalarea2
    print("The combined area of both houses is",totalbothhouses)


def calcRectArea(RectAreaTotal, width):

    '''
calcRectArea prompts the user to enter width, height, and length, computes the
front and side areas, and adds them to compute rectangular area
'''



    height=input("Enter the height: ")
    height=int(height)

    length=input("Enter the length: ")
    length=int(length)

    front=(width*height)
    side=(length*height)

    RectAreaTotal=(front*2)+(side*2)
    return RectAreaTotal,width

def calcTriArea(totalgablearea, width):

    '''
    calcTriArea has the user enter the gable height and computes triangular area
    '''

    gableheight=input("Enter the gable height: ")
    gableheight=int(gableheight)

    totalgablearea=(gableheight)         
    return totalgablearea
```